# Showing that a non-negative random variable has a finite expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X \geqslant 0$ be a random variable on a probability space $\left( {\Omega ,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}} \right)$. Show that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] <  + \infty $ if and only if $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {n\mathbb{P}\left( {n - 1 \leqslant X < n} \right)}  <  + \infty $.

My solution: $$\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {X{1_{n - 1 \leqslant X < n}}} } \right] = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {\mathbb{E}\left[ {X{1_{n - 1 \leqslant X < n}}} \right]}  \leqslant \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {\mathbb{E}\left[ {n{1_{n - 1 \leqslant X < n}}} \right]}  = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {n\mathbb{P}\left( {n - 1 \leqslant X < n} \right)}  <  + \infty $$

where the second equality follows from Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem and the inequality from the monotonicity of expectation. How to show that the converse also holds?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] <  + \infty  \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[ {X + 1} \right] <  + \infty $ and apply similar reasoning as above

Comment: Why not write it (a bit more detailed) as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] <  + \infty  \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[ {X + 1} \right] <  + \infty $ and $$\mathbb{E}\left[ {X + 1} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {\left( {X + 1} \right){1_{n - 1 \leqslant X < n}}} } \right] = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {\mathbb{E}\left[ {\left( {X + 1} \right){1_{n - 1 \leqslant X < n}}} \right]}  \geqslant \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {n\mathbb{P}\left( {n - 1 \leqslant X < n} \right)} $$

Again, the second equality follows from the LMCT and the inequality from the monotonicity of expectation and the fact that $X \geqslant 0$.
So, $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] <  + \infty  \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[ {X + 1} \right] <  + \infty $ which implies $$\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {n\mathbb{P}\left( {n - 1 \leqslant X < n} \right)}  \leqslant \mathbb{E}\left[ {X + 1} \right] <  + \infty $$ by the inequality above.